# asignar un tema a la aplicativo en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

buenas, tengo una aplicación que tiene un tema creado por defecto en android. lo estaba compilando con un api 23 pero los celulares donde correrá la aplicacion tienen un api 19. descargué el api 19, pero al seleccionar el api 19 en la parte superior del emulador el theme ya no se muestra, ni la barra. en el manifest puse

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

pero igual no se muestra, solo sale con el api23. muestro pantallas de la 19 y 23 respectivamente. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el style que uso :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> 
<!-- Customize your theme here. --> 
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> 
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> 
 </style>
```

Comment: Para poder desplegar componentes tipo Material (como los que veo en tu captura de abajo) en APIs menores que la 21, necesitas utilizar la libreria de compatibilidad `com.android.support:design:23.2.1` o la versión más reciente de ella.

Comment: @ICRUZ Podrías agregar en tu pregunta el "style" completo que tiene definido?

Comment: @Elenasys, ya está.

Comment: @RosendoRopher desde el sdk launcher?

Comment: @ICRUZ, ok ahora dentro de res\values\styles.xml que es: AppTheme ?

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style> @Elenasys

Comment: noto que usas appCompat, ya probaste en un dispositivo real de api 19 ? no creo que debas tener problema! :)

Comment: si, en un galxay nexus  de api 19

Comment: @RosendoRopher ya descargué el design;23.2.1 pero sigue igual

Comment: No es solo descargarla, es utilizarla amigo :)

Comment: Instala una versión actualizada de Android Studio y con create new proyect, asignas min api a 16 y la target a 23 y te generara todo correctamente, deberias mirar un tutorial base sobre android

Answer (score 2):

Cosa que debes tener en cuentra sobre temas en Android

res/values/style.xml => estilo donde se aplicará en todos las versiones

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> 
<!-- Customize your theme here. --> 
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> 
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> 
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> 
 </style>
```

res/values-21/style.xml => estilo donde solo se aplicará la versión api 21

la Actividad debe de exterder de `AppCompatActivity`

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`

A parte de eso, no ser que versión de Android Studio tienes, las más recientes, con crear un proyecto nuevo el mismo te lo arma para que funcione bien, añade la librería de compatibilidad para usar Material Design.

Comment: no tuve tiempo de agregar una respuesta pero creo que esto sería una respuesta para solucionar este problema.

Comment: gracias, pero yo ya extiendo ListActivity. que yo sepa no se puede extender dos veces .-.

Answer (score 1):

Bien, en tu archivo `build.gradle` debiste haber añadido algo como esto

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    .....
}
```

Así que ahora puedes utilizar los componentes (widgets) de la librearía, por ejemplo para el `AppBarLayout` puedes hacer algo como esto

```
<!-- Resto de tu Layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"></include>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Nota el prefijo `android.support.design.widget` para `AppBarLayout`, el el ejemplo use un `include` por ende debes tener un `xml` llamado `tool_bar.xml` con el siguiente contenido (notar el prefijo)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/in_black"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

En tu `style.xml` (por ejemplo) podrías tener algo como esto

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">tu primary color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">tu primary dark color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">tu accent color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">etc ...</item>"
</style>
```

El detalle está en utilizar aquellos componentes que solo están disponibles para API's >= 21 a través de la librería de compatibilidad.

Como comentas, API 19 es Android 4 (y por tu captura) pero componentes con look and feel Material solo están disponibles de manera nativa para API >=21 (Android 5 o superior)

Si tienes alguna duda te recomiendo leer este [post](https://www.sitepoint.com/material-design-android-design-support-library/) que aunque esté en inglés es muy intuitivo y podrás despejar esas dudas.